# How can I work with layouts in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, variables, layout, android-resources

Can I work somehow with layouts from resources folder in java?
I have a layout in the resorces folder which contains a RelativeLayout which contains a LinearLayout, and any TextViews. And I want to create something like a class instance, and change in example the RelativeLayout background and the texts in the TextViews.
Because then I want to convert this to a Bitmap (for which I have already written the function).
And I don't want it to show up. All this in a static function.
It's possible? How do I create a something like variable/class?
Sorry for any spelling or composition errors I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    fun getLayout(layoutId: Int, context: Context) : ViewGroup {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, null, false) as ViewGroup 
    }
```

This is how you would get a Layout from the resources directory programmatically. Using it like so:

```
val myLayout = getLayout(R.layout.activity_main, context)
```

Changing the background

```
  myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
```

Changing some text

```
 myLayout.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.my_text_view).setText("Hello World")
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I need!